# Q: Googles OR TOOLS, conjunctive arcs

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools

Im currently reading the laymans theory behind the job shop problem written in OR TOOLS. I have come by an annotation that I do not understand, hopefully somehow here could help me.

http://www.lia.disi.unibo.it/Staff/MicheleLombardi/or-tools-doc/user_manual/manual/ls/jobshop_def_data.html

In the above link, step 6.1.3 the notation l is introduced as a part of the conjunctive arcs, can anyone see what this l is a notation for? It isn't in the theory "they" introduce and I can't seem to link it to general job scheduling or mixed graph theory.

Kind regards

Comment: `k` is a task and `l` another one, it is just to iterate between pair of tasks

Comment: t_k is a task, since k denotes a vertex? So you mean that l is another vertex ? Following that your logic, how would you explain the two constraints? conjunctive and disjunctive ?

Ps. Thx for replying :)

Comment: start + duration of task i <= start task i + 1, the first one is for precedences and the second one to avoid overlaps, I might be wrong though

Comment: I see it the same way "start + duration of task i <= start task i + 1". I think its their notation thats a bit messy since they dont introduce t_l as an increment of t_k. 
Let's see if anyone else chimes in. Either way, thank you for the input

Comment: Actually, they define C as "a set of conjunctive arcs between the i^th and (i+1)th tasks of a job." so their notation is correct

Comment: you are right! Thx for input